# renaming array using foreach on controller and view:

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm having a problem, I tried renaming my `$query->result_array()` using `foreach` on my `controller` and called it in `view` using another `foreach` to display the result from `$query->result_array();`

Here's how I did it.

My `controller`:

I have this user-defined function named `logs()`, I have a query inside and used `$query->result_array()` to get the results. Then I renamed it using `foreach{}` like this code below:

```
    $result     = array();
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
        $result = array(
            "id"         => $row['id'],
            "name"       => $row['name'],
            "status"     => $row['status'],
            "time"       => $row['time']
            );
    }
    return $result;
```

Then I created another user-defined function named `filtered_logs()` to filter the result from `logs()` *I filtered it because I have multiple tables to `LEFT JOIN` it with.

```
    $filtered   = array();
    $logs       = $this->logs();

    if ($logs['status'] == "ok") {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table a 
                                    LEFT JOIN table b 
                                    ON a.image = b.image
                                    LEFT JOIN ....ON...
                                    WHERE a.id = '".$logs['id']."'");

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
            $filtered = array(

                "path"     => $row['path'],
                "grade"    => $row['grade'],
                "time"     => $logs['time'],
                );
        }
    }
```

Sending these results to `view` I used this method, placed on the `index` of the `controller`.

```
   $data['logs'] = $this->filtered_logs();
   $this->load->view('pages', $data);
```

Then displayed it on `view` using these codes:

```
   <?php
      foreach ($logs as $row) {
        echo $row['id']." </br>";
        echo $row['status']." </br>";
        echo $row['time']." </br>";
      }
   ?>
```

but when I do use this way of handling result_array, it gives me an error saying " Illegal string offset '' "

Can someone help me or tell me if there's another way of displaying the results of my queries?

Comment: for one thing, you'd might want to add bracet [] like this: $result[] = array(...) instead of $result = array(...). Otherwise you are not adding element to $array but assigning a new value.

Comment: u r missed a single quotes in  "name"       => $row['name'],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are missing "[]" after $result array where you are feeding data in it in for each loop and it is causing this error.

It should be like this:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
    $result[] = array(
        "id"         => $row['id'],
        "name"       => $row['name'],
        "status"     => $row['status'],
        "time"       => $row['time']
        );
}
return $result;
```

Comment: I'll try doing this later, please wait for the result. Thank you

Comment: This helps! Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an other way of displaying the results try it.

```
    <?php
          foreach ($logs as $row) {
            echo $row->id." </br>";
            echo $row->status." </br>";
            echo $row->time." </br>";
          }
       ?>
```

Comment: I have noticed you have not closed the braces on 'name' replace this line 
"name"       => $row['name], with   "name"       => $row['name'],

Comment: Sorry that is just a typo here in stackoverflow, I'll try doing this please wait for my respond thank you

Comment: I'm sorry to inform you but this is not working, still, thanks for helping me out. I already found an answer. :)

Comment: Good, Post your answer here so, it will be helpful for anyone who will face a similar problem in future! Thanks.